# $(xy)^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}$ if and only if $G$ is Abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to prove the following statement: $(xy)^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}$ $\forall x,y\in G$ if and only if $G$ is Abelian. $G$ is a group and $x,y\in G$. This is what I did:

If $G$ is Abelian, then $(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}$ for all $x,y\in G$.
Now suppose that $(xy)^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}$ holds for all $x,y\in G$, we also know that $(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}$, so $y^{-1}x^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}$ and $G$ has to be Abelian.

Is this proof complete or not? Thank you.

Comment: The problem as stated is not quite correct. The correct statement is is $(xy)^{-1}=x^{-1}y^{-1}\ \forall x,y\in G$ if and only if $G$  is abelian. (You make use of the statement in the correct form in the proof you give.)

Comment: Yes, just note that $G = \{ x^ {-1} : x \in G \} $.

Comment: Almost. You showed in the second part that $x^{-1}$ and $y^{-1}$ commute. Can you show that $x$ and $y$ themselves commute? (Also, the problem statement seems to lack some quantifiers for $x,y$, but you used tehm correctly in your (almost) proof)

Comment: Essentially complete. It would look better if you applied the result to $x=a^{-1}$, $y=b^{-1}$, then you would get $ab=ba$.

Comment: @FrankMuer : I deleted your edit to the question because it's the sort of thing that belongs in a comment or an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your proof does capture the essential idea it leaves out a detail that the professor probably wants you to be explicit about because you're in an introductory class.  The direction $G$ Abelian implies $(xy)^{-1} = x^{-1}y^{-1}$ is perfectly fine, but for the other direction you've shown that $x^{-1}y^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1}$ for all $x$ and $y$.  You are supposed to show that $xy = yx$ for all $x$ and $y$.  The general format of the proof should be as follows:

1. Assume $x, y \in G$.
2. Use the assumption to calculate $yx$.
3. Conclude that $xy = yx$.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof is basically correct; you're one step away from finishing. You end by concluding that $x^{-1}y^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}$. What we really want is $xy=yx$.

Answer (score 1):

try... this ..

by definition, 'e' as identity
$$(xy)^{-1} = (xy)^{-1}\cdot e \cdot e$$

$$= (xy)^{-1}\cdot (xx^{-1})(yy^{-1})$$ 
 $$= (xy)^{-1}\cdot (x)(x^{-1}\cdot y)(y^{-1})$$ 
 $$= (xy)^{-1}\cdot (x)(y\cdot  x^{-1} )(y^{-1})$$ 
 $$= (xy)^{-1}\cdot (x y)\cdot  (x^{-1} )(y^{-1})$$ 
 $$= e \cdot x^{-1}  y^{-1}$$ 
$$=  x^{-1} y^{-1}$$

NOW the other way.. 
$$xy = xy\cdot e =  xy \cdot (yx)^{-1}(yx) = xy \cdot y^{-1}x^{-1}(yx) = x(y \cdot y^{-1})x^{-1}(yx)=x\cdot e\cdot x^{-1}\cdot yx = yx$$

----->>>>>>>>>in case you need further explanations.. some of the steps are typically justified by somthing like this.. ----below....

by definition, 'e' as identity
$$(xy)^{-1} = (xy)^{-1}\cdot e \cdot e$$

$$= (xy)^{-1}\cdot (xx^{-1})(yy^{-1})$$\tag{by definition of inverses}\
 $$= (xy)^{-1}\cdot (x)(x^{-1}\cdot y)(y^{-1})$$\tag{by associativity of groups}\
 $$= (xy)^{-1}\cdot (x)(y\cdot  x^{-1} )(y^{-1})$$\tag{[important :-)] using abelian  assumption}\
 $$= (xy)^{-1}\cdot (x y)\cdot  (x^{-1} )(y^{-1})$$\tag{associative prop of groups}\
 $$= e \cdot x^{-1}  y^{-1}$$\tag{def of inverses}\
$$=  x^{-1} y^{-1}$$\tag{def of identity}\